# Steam Game Icon

Tags: c#, image, icons, steam

I am making a file explorer and for the thumbnail view it requires the icon of a file. I have gotten an icon for all of the files except for steam games. I have looked around and cannot find a way to get the icon like Windows does.

Edit:
This is what i currently use to get my file icons:

```
public static Bitmap GetBigImage(string path, Size size)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);

        if (ext == ".exe")
        {
            Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path);
            bmp = ico.ToBitmap();
            ico.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            if (imageType.Contains(ext.Replace(".", "")))
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
                bmp = new Bitmap(img, new Size(size.Width - 20, 80));
                img.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                Icon ico = Win32.GetLargeIconForExtension(ext);
                bmp = ico.ToBitmap();
                ico.Dispose();
            }
        }

        return bmp;
    }
```

This is the path I am trying to get **steam://rungameid/209170**

In *GetBigImage*, if I see if the path contains *steam://* (in either of the if statements) the method still returns no icon.

Comment: Can you give us an example of a file you are trying to get the icon of.  E.g. what's its full path and name.  I have steam, I might play around with it and figure it out.

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76717007/5514131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Database of Steam Games [here](http://steamdb.info/apps/). Each entry leads to a page that includes a link to the game's icon.

Your ID leads to [this](http://steamdb.info/app/209170/) page where [this](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/209170/4c96165b43204485761d7e79ca209a5ba4b644ec.ico) link points to the icon.

Note that there usually is a real icon under the field 'clienticon' and also a plain jpg strangely named 'icon'!

For an explorer type app I recommend caching those icon.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definitely be caching these icons.

Comment: I need an API to get the game icon programmatically. Do you know where to find the icon's hash code? The [link here](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/209170/4c96165b43204485761d7e79ca209a5ba4b644ec.ico) is of format ```https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/{appid}/{hash}.ico```.

Comment: Sorry, but no, I don't.

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76717007/5514131 which does not require any API or icon caching.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon
```

From the System.Drawing namespace?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yeah that returns a blank icon

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Steam game icon path by using the following Registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and specifying the game ID.

After that use the `Icon` class to load the icon file and convert the Icon to `Bitmap`

[image]

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int gameId = 1449850;

        string iconPath = GetGameIconPath(gameId);

        if (File.Exists(iconPath))
        {

            Icon icon = new Icon(iconPath, new Size(256, 256));
            Bitmap bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

        }

    }

    private static string GetGameIconPath(int gameId)
    {
        try
        {

            RegistryKey regKeyGame = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey($"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\Steam App {gameId}", false);

            if (regKeyGame != null)
            {
                return regKeyGame.GetValue("DisplayIcon", string.Empty).ToString();
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to get the game icon path.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return string.Empty;
        }

    }
}
```

}